# Can't serialize property when its parent inherits from IList<>

Tags: serialization, protobuf-net

I use the following data structure for my `Family` class that inherits from [`IList<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) :

```
public class Family : IList<string>
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }

   //IList<string> members
              .                .
              .

   //IList<string> members
}
```

I create my own `RuntimeTypeModel` and add the `Family` type to it like here :

```
RuntimeTypeModel myModel = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
MetaType familyMetaType = myModel.Add(typeof(Family), true);
familyMetaType.AddField(1, "LastName");
familyMetaType.AddField(2, "Item").IsPacked = true; ;
familyMetaType.CompileInPlace();
myModel.Compile();
```

And then I create a `Family` object and serialize it :

```
Family family = new Family();
family.LastName = "Sawan";
family.Add("Amer");

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Dump.proto", FileMode.Create))
    myModel.Serialize(fs, family);
```

But when I Deserialize it I get only the members of the `string` collection but not the `LastName` value.

What configuration should I set to my `RuntimeTypeModel` to make it serialize the other objects like the `LastName` in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like `XmlSerializer` and several others, protobuf-net draws a hard line between lists and entities. Something cannot be both, as far as protobuf-net is concerned. If you don't want it to choose "list", you can use `IgnoreListHandling` (IIRC) on `[ProtoContract]` - but this will obviously then not serialize the items that are *in* the list. It is usually better to be an object that *has* a name and *has* a list:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Family
{
    [ProtoMember(1)] public string LastName { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)] public IList<string> Items {get{return items;}}

    private readonly IList<string> items = new List<string>();
}
```